# Selenium driver for .Net WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

**GOAL** Is to develop and run selenium scripts for web app pages loaded in webbrowser control  {https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752040(v=vs.85).aspx}.
**Approach** I believe this control internally uses installed IE only and just like selenium's **IEDriverServer.exe** , and I need to implement a new driver for .Net Webbrowser control using IEdriverServer codebase as a starting point. 
I need help with the following

1. Is my approach feasible to achieve?
2. If not then what should be the approach to achieve my goal.
3. Is any solution is already out there and i'm trying to reinvent the wheel.
4. If yes then please give me the pointers.
5. If approach is OK, what should be starting point for this implementation in .Net.

Comment: About 1 year later ... have you able to achieve this goal? I'm interested with this idea too. So far I have performance issue when combining selenium with real browser. I think by using embedded-browser-control can lead to better performance. Any latest selenium driver for headless browser with C# binding (e,g phantomJS driver) is outdated & abandoned.